# python dictionary how can create (structured) unique dictionary list if the key contains list of values of other keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have below unstructured dictionary list which contains values of other keys in a list .

I am not sure if the question i ask is strange. this is the actual dictionary payload that we receive from source which not aligned with respective entry

```
[
  {
    "dsply_nm": [
      "test test",
      "test test",
      "",
      ""
    ],
    "start_dt": [
      "2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00",
      "2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00",
      "2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00",
      "2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00"
    ],
    "exp_dt": [
      "2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00",
      "2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00",
      "2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00",
      "2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00"
    ],
    "hrs_pwr": [
      "14",
      "12",
      "13",
      "15"
    ],
  
    "make_nm": "test",
    "model_nm": "test",
    "my_yr": "1980"
  }
]
```

**"the length of list cannot not be expected and it could be more than 4 sometimes or less in some keys"**

#Expected:
i need to check if the above dictionary are in proper structure or not and based on that it should return the proper dictionary list associate with each item
for eg:

```
def get_dict_list(items):
    if type(items == not structure)
        result = get_associated_dict_items_mapped
        return result
    else:
        return items
       

#Final result
expected_dict_list=
[{"dsply_nm":"test test","start_dt":"2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","exp_dt":"2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","hrs_pwr":"14"},

  {"dsply_nm":"test test","start_dt":"2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","exp_dt":"2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","hrs_pwr":"12","make_nm": "test",model_nm": "test","my_yr": "1980"},

  {"dsply_nm":"","start_dt":"2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","exp_dt":"2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","hrs_pwr":"13"},

  {"dsply_nm":"","start_dt":"2021-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","exp_dt":"2022-04-21T00:01:00-04:00","hrs_pwr":"15"}
]
```

in above dictionary payload, below part is associated with the second dictionary items and have to map respectively

```
   "make_nm": "test",
    "model_nm": "test",
    "my_yr": "1980"
  }
```

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Comment: is it expected that the lists be of the same length? at the moment one has more than the others

Comment: @JonSG it should be the same length.. i have updated the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since customer details is a list

```
dict(zip(customer_details[0], list(customer_details.values[0]())))
```

this yields:

```
{'insured_details': ['asset', 'asset', 'asset'],
 'id': ['213', '214', '233'],
 'dept': ['account', 'sales', 'market'],
 'salary': ['12', '13', '14']}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of list comprehensions will get you going. If you would like me to unwind them into more traditional for loops, just let me know.

```
import json

def get_dict_list(item):
    first_value = list(item.values())[0]

    if not isinstance(first_value, list):
        return [item]

    return [{key: item[key][i] for key in item.keys()} for i in range(len(first_value))]

cutomer_details = [
    {
        "insured_details": "asset",
        "id": "xxx",
        "dept": "account",
        "salary": "12"
    },
    {
        "insured_details": ["asset", "asset", "asset"],
        "id":["213","214","233"],
        "dept":["account","sales","market"],
        "salary":["12","13","14"]
    }
]

cutomer_details_cleaned = []
for detail in cutomer_details:
    cutomer_details_cleaned.extend(get_dict_list(detail))

print(json.dumps(cutomer_details_cleaned, indent=4))
```

That should give you:

```
[
    {
        "insured_details": "asset",
        "id": "xxx",
        "dept": "account",
        "salary": "12"
    },
    {
        "insured_details": "asset",
        "id": "213",
        "dept": "account",
        "salary": "12"
    },
    {
        "insured_details": "asset",
        "id": "214",
        "dept": "sales",
        "salary": "13"
    },
    {
        "insured_details": "asset",
        "id": "233",
        "dept": "market",
        "salary": "14"
    }
]
```

Comment: HI @JonSG, the above code work fine.. but in some case we observed that length of value for some key are not constant . ie if  id is missed in some case id":["213","214"] instead of id":["213","214","233"], i am getting index error- List index out of range.. i will update the question with issue.. could you please look

Comment: Hi @JonSG, i have updated my question with other payload of dictionary which have different structure.. could you please help.. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I specifically asked if the values would have the same length. I'll take a second look,